# Why doesn't this xargs command work?

Tags: bash, text-processing, xargs

I wanted to delete all .sh extensions so did this:

```
ls *.sh | xargs -I {} mv {} `basename {} .sh`
```

However it doesn't work, it behaves like `basename` returns unchanged file name.

Why is it behaving that way ?

For instance, this works:

```
ls *.sh | xargs -I {} echo `basename {}.jpg .jpg`;
```

**EDIT**:

Solution: single quote prevents `` `basename ...` `` evaluation by the shell before the command is run.

```
ls *.sh | xargs -I {}  sh -c 'mv {} `basename {} .sh`'
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Because the basename command is run before the pipeline is run. To make this work you need xargs to execute basename and you can do that with `sh -c`, e.g.:

```
ls *.sh | xargs -L1 sh -c 'basename $1 .sh' dummy
```

Notes:

- If you don't tell `xargs` where to insert the file names they will be added at the end of the command line.
- You should use the `-L1` switch or its equivalent, so `xargs` only passes one argument to `sh`.
- Using the output of `ls` may have [unwanted effects](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

#### Edit

Removed deprecated options, thanks TechZilla

Comment: Your first point is incorrect, unless you meant it's default respective to the `-i` option, but those 'classic' options have been deprecated.  For example to use just one option/line, the new POSIX man page recommends `-L1`.  To call the old behavior of `-i`, the page recommends the `-I'{}'` option.

Comment: So, its actually about '' instead "" symbols. I guess ' prevents shell evaluation of ``. See my edits.

Comment: @TechZilla: thanks for the corrections. @majkinetor: yes and no, you need to delay the evaluation, but I don't think you can use backticks (`).

Comment: @thor: +1, You're a class act, don't see that enough around the SE's.

Comment: I am sure it works because of single quote. Actually, I tried with double quotes before I posted and it didn't work. The same as in `echo '``basename ...``'`

Comment: @majkinetor: ah, I see what you mean now. To rename files in this manner I would rather use `rename`, e.g.: `rename 's/\.sh//' *.sh`. Try first with dry-run (`-n`).

Comment: @majkinetor: `rename` does work great, and fairly simple, but remember it's very distribution specific.  RHEL and Debian based distributions provide different `rename` commands, so one must keep that in mind when creating cross-distro scripts.

Comment: thanks to this I could do `sh -c 'scp $1 target:/path/to/$(basename $1)'` but hey, this `dummy` is magic.

Comment: wrt. rename, [this answer of mine on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11809805/1331399) and the comments below it have some details on how to make it work on various systems

Answer (score 4):

I'm unsure about your question, are you actually asking why your first line doesn't work?  Or are you looking for a proper method to rename all the .sh files?

Assuming it's the cleanest method, I prefer to prepare command options before `xargs`.
For removing a .sh file extension, I often consider this approach,

```
 find -maxdepth 1 -type f -iname '*.sh'  | sed 'p;s_.sh$__' | xargs -L2 mv
```